# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object PlayerMovement.Update ()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    private CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 direction;
    public float speed = 15f;
    void start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        direction.z = speed;
        controller.Move(direction * Time.deltaTime);
    }  
}
```

Why i am getting this error?
I am using unity5.3
this is the full error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> PlayerMovement.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerMovement.cs:16)

Comment: Have you confirmed that `start` is called, and that `controller` is assigned a value?

Comment: Be aware that Unityscript and C# are both two completely different programming languages, so you should only tag one of them. Your code is C#.

Comment: `direction` is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Either `controller` or `direction` isn't initialized. Make sure they are before your call to `Update()`.